# :last vs :last-child selector

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I've noticed that `$( 'filter:last' )` is different from `$( 'filter:last-child' )` in jQuery.

I tried the jQuery docs but had a hard time understanding what additional purpose `:last` serves and why they both exist.

Apparently, `:last` is a jQuery extension and not in the CSS specification. So, the question came to my mind of how it is different from the traditional `:last-child`. Also, there happens to be a `.last()` method in jQuery which is said to be more efficient than `$( 'filter:last' )`, so what use does the `:last` selector have?

Comment: [From the docs](https://api.jquery.com/last-child-selector/): _While :last matches only a single element, :last-child can match more than one: one for each parent._ - what part of this is unclear?

Comment: I was looking at [this](https://api.jquery.com/last/). My mistake.

Comment: @cale_b: The part were one should read the doc. ;)

Comment: There is [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) and [`:nth-last-child()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:nth-last-child) too... ;)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They are very similar. The difference is that if you have something like

```
<div>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>bye</p>
</div>
<div>
  <p>hi</p>
  <p>bye</p>
</div>
```

`$('p:last-child')` will select both `<p>bye</p>` elements whereas `$('p:last')` will select only the second one. It's also true that the same thing can be done with `$('p').last()`, by adding `:last` as a selector jQuery allows for using filter with `:last` without having to make the argument of the filter be a function.

Comment: Answer saved my life! Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

The **:last** selector matches **only a single element**, **:last-child** can match more than one: one for each parent.

See below example for better illustration-

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="utf-8">
 <title>last-child demo</title>
  <style>
 span.solast {
   text-decoration: line-through;
  }
 </style>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
 </head>
<body>

<div>
 <span>John,</span>
 <span>Karl,</span>
 <span>Brandon,</span>
 <span>Sam</span>
</div>
 <div>
  <span>Glen,</span>
  <span>Tane,</span>
  <span>Ralph,</span>
  <span>David</span>
 </div>
<table>
  <tr><td>First Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Middle Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Last Row</td></tr>
</table>

<table>
  <tr><td>Second Table First Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Second Table Middle Row</td></tr>
  <tr><td>Second Table Last Row</td></tr> 
</table>


<script>
$( "div span:last-child" )
 .css({ color:"red", fontSize:"80%" })
 .hover(function() {
    $( this ).addClass( "solast" );
  }, function() {
    $( this ).removeClass( "solast" );
  });

$( "table tr:last" ).css({ backgroundColor: "yellow", fontWeight: "bolder" 
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

You can see that in above code :last selector changes background color Yellow of only one tr not the both tr which means :last selects only single element. Whereas :last-child will select each elements last child.

Comment: *«better illustration»* would be optimized with a code snippet. Explore the icons of the edit mode a little.

Comment: Good example, but @LouysPatriceBessette makes a good point. Try editing your post and optimizing it a little bit using a code snippet.

Comment: HI @LouysPatriceBessette i am new to stackoverflow, could you please mention how to use code snippet here, I am not very sure what you are talking about

Comment: Here is a fully detailled blog post about [SO code snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).